# If http redirects to https, will redirect trigger, if HSTS in use?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, https, hsts

Since sites switch to HTTPS, there should be for the Googlebot double crawl affort on crawling links - because of additional hops, with redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. It should be pretty big amount of computational capacity, which is needed for this.

I'm thinking about, whether Googlebot accomplishes indeed the doubled affort, or it has any hint to recognize HTTPS and to go directly to it without to trigger redirect to spare the additional hops?

- Is it correct, that if HSTS is adjusted correctly, so the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS wouln't be triggered and traffic gioes directly to HTTPS?
- Could it be that Googlebot, which is probably headless Chrome, has a clue/hint to recognize HTTPS behind HTTP to go directly to HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Googlebot does not store HSTS nor look at the preload list. This was discussed at this issue: https://github.com/chromium/hstspreload.org/issues/67

To be honest the computational expense of following a redirect is tiny compared to the computational expensive of downloading all the resources a page needs and then accurately render and index it. Redirects are a standard part of the web and crawlers are well able to handle them.

Additionally websites will follow links, including sitemaps and canonical URLs in the HEAD section of the HTML. They don't just randomly go to websites they don't know about and crawl HTTP. So if HTTPS is used everywhere for a site there should be very little crawling of HTTP URLs anyway.

Finally this question is probably better suited to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com rather than Stack Overflow.